# Can I use a socket through multiple HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

For example, if a user enters my webapp through the standard index.html page that is loaded automatically, can that socket still be used if the user clicks a button on my webpage that loads another html page thats part of my webapp? Right now, I have one front end js page that is used for my 3 html files. It works fine for my standard index file, but when I click a button that leads to another html file (Which is also connected to my front end js page), it says that io is not defined in the console.

Comment: Think of each distinct page a browser loads as a distinct application. If this wasn't the case, there would be *huge* security problems, compared to the ones that we already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading a new HTML page will cause the Javascript on the new page to execute - this will destroy any context from the previous page (including established connections).

There are a couple of ways around this:

1. write your code to re-establish the connection on page load. This will require passing an identifier of some sort so the new connection is associated with the existing session.
2. write your application as a single page app (SPA). In an SPA, the pages are rendered on the client side, as part of a Javascript app passed to the client on the first load. Thus, since there is no reload when a user is moving from one page to another, the connection is not lost.